# Laravel cant read file storage

Tags: laravel

Why is it that when I copy my project and removed the original one with my copied one, It can't read the file storage directory? The two literally has the same code

Comment: This is probably to do with file directory permissions and ownership.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to run the commands:

`sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache`

`sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache`